# Framework not found Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Since I was using `Fabric Crashlytics` and it has been deprecated so I want to delete the Pods and change to `Firebase Crashlytics`. My Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  # Flutter Pod
  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end

pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
```

Earlier my Pods were like:

```
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.9.0'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.12.0'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
```

I deleted Podfile.lock and Pods folder and did `pod init` and `pod install`. Deleted `DerivedData` folder and cleaned build folder.

Also in Link Binary with Libraries I haven't included this framework:
[image: Link Binary With Libraries]

Also have I made sure I am opening `xcworkspace` not `xcodeproj`.

Below is the content of the file `Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig`

```
ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseABTesting-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCore-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseInstallations-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseInstanceID-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseRemoteConfig-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GTMSessionFetcher-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleDataTransport-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleToolboxForMac-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/PromisesObjC-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Protobuf-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/file_picker" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/firebase_analytics" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/firebase_core" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/flutter_tts" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb-framework" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/open_file" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/shared_preferences" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/url_launcher" "${PODS_ROOT}/../Flutter" "${PODS_ROOT}/Crashlytics/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/iOS" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebasePerformance/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks" "${PODS_ROOT}/GoogleSignIn/Frameworks"
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 $(inherited) GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 $(inherited) PB_FIELD_32BIT=1 PB_NO_PACKED_STRUCTS=1 PB_ENABLE_MALLOC=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseABTesting-framework/FirebaseABTesting.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCore-framework/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics-framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseInstallations-framework/FirebaseInstallations.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseInstanceID-framework/FirebaseInstanceID.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/FirebaseRemoteConfig-framework/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GTMSessionFetcher-framework/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleDataTransport-framework/GoogleDataTransport.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport-framework/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleToolboxForMac-framework/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/GoogleUtilities-framework/GoogleUtilities.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/PromisesObjC-framework/FBLPromises.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Protobuf-framework/protobuf.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/file_picker/file_picker.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle/flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/flutter_tts/flutter_tts.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/nanopb-framework/nanopb.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/open_file/open_file.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/shared_preferences/shared_preferences.framework/Headers" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/url_launcher/url_launcher.framework/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Firebase" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseABTesting" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalyticsInterop" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstallations" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/FirebaseRemoteConfig" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GTMSessionFetcher" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransport" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleToolboxForMac" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/PromisesObjC" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Protobuf" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/nanopb" $(inherited) ${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources "${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/Sources/FBLPromises/include"
LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) '@executable_path/Frameworks' '@loader_path/Frameworks'
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++" -l"sqlite3" -l"z" -framework "CoreGraphics" -framework "CoreTelephony" -framework "CoreText" -framework "Crashlytics" -framework "FBLPromises" -framework "FIRAnalyticsConnector" -framework "Fabric" -framework "FirebaseABTesting" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseCoreDiagnostics" -framework "FirebaseInstallations" -framework "FirebaseInstanceID" -framework "FirebasePerformance" -framework "FirebaseRemoteConfig" -framework "Flutter" -framework "Foundation" -framework "GTMSessionFetcher" -framework "GoogleAppMeasurement" -framework "GoogleDataTransport" -framework "GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport" -framework "GoogleSignIn" -framework "GoogleToolboxForMac" -framework "GoogleUtilities" -framework "LocalAuthentication" -framework "QuartzCore" -framework "SafariServices" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit" -framework "file_picker" -framework "firebase_analytics" -framework "firebase_core" -framework "flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle" -framework "flutter_tts" -framework "nanopb" -framework "open_file" -framework "protobuf" -framework "shared_preferences" -framework "url_launcher"
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -D COCOAPODS
PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES = YES
```

Comment: you may have an "import Crashlytics" statement in your code.
Also check for Run Script

Comment: I have removed the import statement and replace with FirebaseCrashlytics. Inside my Flutter folder there's a file Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig that has statements that includes deprecated frameworks. Might be this would be the issue. How can I regenerate these files, any idea?

Comment: If you haven't been using this, please use this guide to correctly update your dependencies and code if you're trying to upgrade from the Fabric to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios. Missing any steps or mixing integrations can cause errors.